# Meta query with multiple values not working

Tags: php, wordpress, wordpress-theming

Ok, I've searched a lot for this issue... I can't make it work...

I have users registered for X class, the thing is that the same user can be registered in two classes so I used ACF checkbox to add it to the profile and so far so good

The thing is that when I make the query to bring up the tasks assigned to that class, it wroks when its a single value but breaks when there are mutliple ones...

the array for the meta query returns this

```
Array ( [0] => Array ( [key] => p_class [value] => tc [compare] => LIKE ) [1] => Array ( [key] => p_class [value] => yb [compare] => LIKE ) [2] => Array ( [key] => p_class [value] => m1 [compare] => LIKE ) [3] => Array ( [key] => p_class [value] => m2 [compare] => LIKE ) [4] => Array ( [key] => p_class [value] => m3 [compare] => LIKE ) )
```

And this is the code I'm using to create the query ...

HELP PLEASE!!

```
    if($_GET['uID']){
    $uData = get_userdata( $_GET['uID'] );
}else{
    $uData = wp_get_current_user(); 
}

$myClass = get_field('p_class', 'user_'.$uData->ID);
$meta_q = array();

foreach($myClass as $class){
    $meta_q[] = array(
        'key' => 'p_class',
        'value' => $class,
        'compare' => 'LIKE'
    );
}
print_r($meta_q);
$args = array(
    'post_type'  => 'task',
    'relation' => 'OR',
    'meta_query' => $meta_q
);



$the_query = new WP_Query( $args );
```

Answer (score 0):

Ok.. So I finally found it... Hope this helps ANYONE out there...

When you fill in the $args array, you must add [0] to the $meta_q array ... so it qould look like this... everything is perfect, except for this:

```
$args = array(
'post_type'  => 'task',
'relation' => 'OR',
'meta_query' => $meta_q[0] 
);
```